# search a string in a text file after a particular string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose this is the text file which has 10 line content.

```
1 mpe:p01 
2 mpe:p02 
3 * xyz 3 
4 mpe:p04 
5 mpe:p05 
6 mpe:p06 
7 mpe:p07 
8 mpe:p08 
9 mpe:p09 
10 mpe:p100
```

I need to search string "mpe:" after "xyz" string.

My piece of code is:

```
str1_name ="* xyz"  
str2_name = "mpe:" ` 

lines = [] 

with open("textfile.txt",'r') as f:
   for line in f:
       if str2_name in line:
           lines.append(line)  
        lines2=lines[0]  
    print(lines2)
```

it is giving me output:

> 1 mpe:p0

but I want the output:

> 4 mpe:p0

Comment: You are not checking for `str1_name` before you check for `str2_name`.  Are you sure it is printing `4 mpe:p04`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, if you're sure *mpe* follows *xyz*, you could run something like:

```
str1_name ="* xyz"  

with open("textfile.txt",'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        while str1_name not in line:
            pass
        if str2_name in line:
            print(next(f))
```

If the searched string doesn't follow immediately :

```
str1_name ="* xyz"
str2_name = "mpe:"  

checkpoint = False

with open("textfile.txt",'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if str1_name in line:
            checkpoint = True
        if checkpoint and str2_name in line:
            print(line)
            break
```

Comment: i need to search mpe follows xyz, here mpe is not next to xyz
1 mpe:p01 
2 mpe:p02 
3 * xyz 3 
4 * mp12:p04 
5 mpZ:p04 
6 mp34:p04 
7 mpe:p05 
8 mpe:p06 
9 mpe:p07 
10mpe:p08 
11mpe:p09 
12mpe:p100

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if you encountered string `xyz` first. If you did, then set a flag to true. Then continue reading file. If previous line read was `xyz`, the flag would have been set to `True`. Check if current line has `mpe` and append that line to `lines`. See if this code works.

```
str1_name ="* xyz"  
str2_name = "mpe:" 
prev_xyz = False

lines = [] 

with open("textfile.txt",'r') as f:
    for line in f:
       if str2_name in line and prev_xyz:
           lines.append(line.strip())  
           #lines2=lines[0] prev line will strip out \n
       if str1_name in line:
           prev_xyz = True
       else:
           prev_xyz = False
print(lines)
```

Output:

```
['4 mpe:p04']
```

Comment: a little correction here, i need to search mpe follows xyz, here mpe is not next to xyz, file is like this:

1 mpe:p01 
2 mpe:p02 
3 * xyz 3 
4 * mp12:p04 
5 mpZ:p04 
6 mp34:p04 
7 mpe:p05 
8 mpe:p06 
9 mpe:p07 
10mpe:p08 
11mpe:p09 
12mpe:p100

Comment: let me understand correctly. If the file is as you posted in comments, then you will have no results. Is that correct? You are searching for a line that contains `mpe` immediately following a line that contains `xyz`. Also, I realized that the new file you posted in comments is not the same as the one in original ask. Looks like the requirements got updated. Will update code and post,

Comment: i checked again. this works irrespective of the change in file. So what is the problem with my code pls? I assume you still want all occurrences of lines that are immediately following `xyz`. In other words, if the file has two occurrences of `xyz`, then you want both to be printed. lets say line 3 and line 9 have `xyz` and the lines immediately following them lines 4 and 10 have `mpe`, then you want to lines 4 and 10 and not break after finding 4. correct?

Answer (score -1):

```
lines = []
line_after_str1=[]

str1_name ="* xyz"

str2_name = "mpe:" 

with open("textfile.txt",'r') as f:
    all_lines=f.readlines()
    for line in range(len(all_lines)):
        
        if str1_name in all_lines[line]:
            line_after_str1.append(all_lines[line+1].replace('\n',''))
        elif str2_name in all_lines[line]:
            lines.append(all_lines[line].replace('\n',''))
        

print(line_after_str1)
```

> Output:

```
['4 mpe:p04']
```

Comment: im not sure, but using `strip('\n')` also works right? instead of `replace('\n','')` method?

Comment: @CoolCloud yes!

Comment: i dont think this is what the OP is asking for. The ask is if line has `str1_name` , then read the next line and  check if it contains `mpe`. Then print that out. I dont think your code is doing that

Comment: a little correction here, i need to search mpe follows xyz, here mpe is not next to xyz, file is like this:

1 mpe:p01 
2 mpe:p02 
3 * xyz 3 
4 * mp12:p04 
5 mpZ:p04 
6 mp34:p04 
7 mpe:p05 
8 mpe:p06 
9 mpe:p07 
10mpe:p08 
11mpe:p09 
12mpe:p100